# Django/Docker/Logging: log files are empty

Tags: python, django, docker, logging, docker-compose

I try to implement logging in my Django project (stack: Django,Docker,Postgresql)

It work in my dev environnement but not in preproduction (linux/Debian)

I got no error but files are empty

I look for permission on files and set chmod 777 to my log files for test but doesn't work neither

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['files_info','files_debug'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'INFO',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'files_info': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': './logsfiles/info',
            'formatter': 'mereva',
        },
        'files_debug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': './logsfiles/debug',
            'formatter': 'mereva',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'mereva': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        }
    },
}
```

views.py

```
# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger('django')

def home(request):

    authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated
    if authenticated:
        print('Connected user',request.user)
        logger.info('User :{0}'.format(request.user.username))

    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Comment: try to rebuild your project and tell us if it works

Comment: you are right, it works now but only log info from home view is written in logs files ```INFO 2021-07-09 08:25:24,860 views User :test1```, not all server request as it is for dev environment ; DEBUg is also set to True in preprod so it is not the problem...

Comment: # This retrieves a Python logging instance (or creates it)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) , as well u should name ur file ./logsfiles/debug.log'

Answer (score 0):

Hi change please files_debug section to :

```
file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'file',
            'filename': './logsfiles/debug.log'
```

as well check the permession of ur file /logsfiles if u have the right to modify it .

change logger instance to :

```
 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```